# Can "V-ing" be replacable with "as"?

Tags: grammaticality, as

To avoid the repetition of using *as*, I decide to replace it with *being*:

> As you can see, I find a pleasure in helping community. At the same time, **being** a person who work in science, I also find the need to do everything productivity and efficiency.

Is it grammatically correct? Can it also work with other verbs (e.g. working in the science)?

Comment: Ooker, please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. For info about why this is helpful, please see “[Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700)”. (_I'd_ certainly like to see more answers, especially one that explains what's going on with present participles vs. "as".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although "being" is not ungrammatical, it is not an improvement over "as" there.

---

Some other corrections:

- We "find pleasure in" rather than "find *a* pleasure in..."
- helping *the* community
- person who *work**s***
- And in the final sentence of your example, you need adverbs, not nouns:

  > do everything *productively* and *efficiently*

Comment: "Being" is neither particularly better nor worse than "as". If he just used "as" in the previous sentence, he might want to use "being" just to add variety to the text. Or vice versa.

Comment: Also, I think "a person who works in science" is a little awkward. I'd be more likely to say, "a person who works in a scientific field" or "a person who works in the sciences". Maybe others disagree, this is pretty subjective.

Comment: @Jay: it's a matter of style, which is subjective, but I find "being a person who" a far greater infelicity than a repeated "as". (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(being+a+person+who)%2C(as+someone+who)%2C(as+one+who)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28being%20a%20person%20who%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28as%20someone%20who%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28as%20one%20who%29%3B%2Cc0)